# How to create Regex that contains Not colon char?

Tags: c#, regex

I have created a regular expression that seems to be working somewhat:

```
// look for years starting with 19 or 20 followed by two digits surrounded by spaces.
    // Instead of ending space, the year may be followed by a '.' or ';'
    static Regex regex = new Regex(@" 19\d{2} | 19\d{2}. | 19\d{2}; | 20\d    {2} | 20\d{2}. | 20\d{2}; ");
// Trying to add 'NOT followed by a colon'
static Regex regex = new Regex(@" 19\d{2}(?!:) | 19\d{2}. | 19\d{2}; | 20\d{2}(?!:) | 20\d{2}. | 20\d{2}; ");
    // Trying to optimize --
    //static Regex regex = new Regex(@" (19|20)\d{2}['.',';']");
```

You can see where I tried to optimize a bit.
But more importantly, it is finding a match for 2002:

How do I make it not do that?

I think I am looking for some sort of NOT operator?

Comment: by "not colon char" do you mean "does not contain `:`"?

Comment: Note that your regex will match `" 19٠٠ "`

Comment: by not contain I should really say not followed by.
We want these possibilities:
19dd
19dd.
19dd;
20dd
20dd:
20dd;
all surrounded by spaces

Answer (score 1):

```
(?:19|20)\d{2}(?=[ ,;.])
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sJ9gM7/103

Comment: The `1984.` case is missing: `(?:19|20)\d{2}(?=[ .,;])`

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather go with `\b` here, this will help deal with other punctuation that may appear after/before the years:

```
\b(?:19|20)[0-9]{2}\b
```

C#:

```
 static Regex regex = new Regex(@"\b(?:19|20)[0-9]{2}\b");
```

Tested in Expresso:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Problem in your regex is dot.

You should have something like this:

```
static Regex regex = 
 new Regex(@" 19\d{2} | 19\d{2}[.] | 19\d{2}; | 20\d{2} | 20\d{2}[.] | 20\d{2}; ");
```

Answer (score 0):

This did it for me:

```
// look for years starting with 19 or 20 followed by two digits surrounded by spaces.
    // Instead of ending space, the year may also be followed by a '.' or ';'
    // but may not be followed by a colon, dash or any other unspecified character.
    // optimized --
    static Regex regex = new Regex(@"(19|20)\d{2} | (19|20)\d{2};| (19|20)\d{2}[.]");
```

Used Regex Tester here:
http://regexhero.net/tester/